# How to generate .car files from artifact folder in WSO2CEP 4.0.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep

I've read this article https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Packaging+Artifacts+as+C-App+Archive#PackagingArtifactsasC-AppArchive-CreatingaC-App

There is a structure in there, but there isn't any information on how to build the .car files. Perhaps anyone know? Thank you..

Comment: I have created a documentation Jira, so this information will be added to the page which you have referred in the question -  https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DOCUMENTATION-2591

Comment: wow.. nice.. thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a car file, you can use WSO2 Developer Studio v3.8.0 (You can download it from [here](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/)).
Refer Developer Studio documentation on [Creating an Analytics Project](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS380/Creating+an+Analytics+Project).

Answer (score 1):

To Generate a .car file you should have [download](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/) WSO2 Developer Studio.

How to create a CAR file
     check this link:
   http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/09/create-deploy-car-file-standalone-wso2-server-wso2-stratos/